# What kind of graph is it?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, coding-theory

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a weighted graph where the vertices are the vectors from euclidian space $R^k$ for any $k = 1,2, \ldots $ and $(v_i,v_j) \in E$ and has weight $w_{ij} \geq 1$ if and only if $v_i$ and $v_j$ have $w_{ij}$ same corresponding co-ordinates. (NOTE: Loops are allowed.)

I just am curious, is it any known graph or related to some known graphs?
Any suggestions will be really beneficial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your edge weights are closely related to Hamming Distance (which would be how many coordinates are *different* rather than how many are equal). Some details of the Hamming graph might be somewhat of interest to you, although they are not usually defined on Euclidean spaces.

Comment: @Rodgers, thanks a lot.